# SSRF change method from POST to GET

Tags: api, ssrf

I'm currently doing a pentest and noticed an endpoint where SSRF is possible. The internal request that is sent is a POST request. I would like to find a way to change it to a GET request. I spun up my own server and created a page that performs a 303 redirect. This helped to change the request to a GET, but the issue is that the JSON data is still included. As a result, I receive a 400 error. Is there a way to remove this JSON data?

I want to use this to access AWS metadata `http://169.254.169.254` as proof of the exploit. Alternatively, is it possible to access another internal endpoint from AWS with a POST request to demonstrate that the exploitation is possible?